# Is a function continuous if sequence definition holds only over 'almost all sequences'?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

By the definition of a continuous function, $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous at $x$ if and only if for any sequence $x_n\to x$, it also holds that $f(x_n)\to f(x)$.

My question is as follows: Suppose $M\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ has measure zero. At every point $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and any convergent sequence $x_n\to x$ such that $x_n\in\mathbb{R}\setminus M$, it also holds that $f(x_n)\to f(x)$.

Is $f$ continuous? For what reason? Or is there a counter-example?

Comment: @Esoog, where I think things are getting delicate is the following reflection: A function is almost everywhere differentiable if and only if for almost all $x$ and any $x_n\to x$, it also holds that $f(x_n)\to f(x)$. From my limited understanding of what you are suggesting, I could be tempted to think that I can also here restrict attention to sequences outside of $M$. However, this cannot be true since the indicator function $1_{x\in\mathbb{Q}}$ is NOT almost everywhere differentiable. Am I missing something?

Comment: Maybe it is me who is missing something, and also I don't know the proof about the almost everywhere differentiable part to comment on this. But the example you just gave doesn't really satisfy the hypothesis right? I presume you take M, the set of measure zero to be the rationals. But then at a rational x, you can take a sequence of irrationals converging to it.

Comment: @Esoog, you are right, the example I just gave is not a counterexample to the question outlined above, because I say that the statement needs to hold for *all* $x$, not just "almost all". I have purposely framed it that way to avoid this obvious counterexample. Nevertheless, the example tells me that this whole thing is really delicate, so I'd really appreciate a more detailed proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, such $f$ is continuous. First, recall that a set of measure zero has empty interior; the argument applies to any set $M$ with empty interior.

Suppose, to the contrary, that there exists $a\in \mathbb{R}$ and a sequence $(x_n)\to a$ such that $f(x_n)$ does not converge to $f(a)$. For each $n$, pick a sequence $(t^{(n)}_k)$ contained in $\mathbb{R}\setminus M$ and converging to $x_n$; such a sequence exists because $M$ has empty interior.

By the assumption, $f(t^{(n)}_k)\to f(x_n)$ as $k\to\infty$. Thus, there exists $k$ such that 
$$|t^{(n)}_k - x_n |<\frac1n\quad\text{ and } \quad 
 |f(t^{(n)}_k) - f(x_n)|<\frac1n$$  Denote this $t^{(n)}_k$ as $s_n $ for brevity. The sequence $(s_n)$ is contained in $\mathbb{R}\setminus M$, converges to $a$, but $f(s_n)\not\to f(a)$. Contradiction.